# Sorting the datatable using calendar component of primefaces

Tags: primefaces, calendar, jsf-2.2

I'm using jsf 2.2 Primefaces 6.0 and i'm trying to sort the datatable using calendar component of primefaces. The issue that when i start filtering the datatable using a specific date all values of datatable will disappear instead of showing the right values.

Here a graphical description through the two pictures:
Data table without filtering:

[image: data table without filtering]

Datatable after filtering:

[image: datatable after filtering]

Here the xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{demandeBean.allDemandes}" var="a" id="t1"
                sortMode="multiple" widgetVar="tt" editable="true" editMode="cell"
                selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{a.id}"
                emptyMessage="Aucune demande" rows="10" paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,25" draggableColumns="true"
                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" paginatorPosition="bottom">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{demandeBean.onRowSelect}"
                    oncomplete="PF('d2').show()" update=":form:d2" />

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{demandeBean.onCellEdit}"
                    update=":form:t1" />

                <p:column headerText="Date dépot" sortBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}" filterBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:calendar id="cal1" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
               <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('tt').filter()" update="t1" />
               <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" oncomplete="PF('tt').filter()" update="t1"/>
            </p:calendar>
         </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{a.dateDeDepot}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                            timeZone="GMT+1:00" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
```

Comment: Don't update the table on the ajax and especially after .filter(), the filter will take care of the update, not sure if this will solve the issue, but it would definitely help, so remove that in the ajax events of the calendar `update="t1"`

Answer (score 0):

add in your column

```
filterMatchMode="contains"
```

so:

```
<p:column headerText="Date dépot" sortBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}" filterBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}" filterMatchMode="contains">
```

Comment: The same issue when i put a specific date all values of the datatable disappear

Comment: try to enter the exact date 22/06/2017 10:01:40, just for testing

Comment: or try to use filterFunction.
see: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39684

Comment: Always the same issue i even delete the time zone in order to verify

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:column headerText="Date dépot" sortBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}" filterBy="#{a.dateDeDepot}" filterFunction="#{a.filterByDate}">
   <f:facet name="filter">
      <h:inputHidden id="filter" />
   </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="header">
        <p:calendar id="cal1" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
           <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('tt').filter()" update="t1" />
           <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" oncomplete="PF('tt').filter()" update="t1"/>
        </p:calendar>
   </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{a.dateDeDepot}">
         <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                        timeZone="GMT+1:00" />
         </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

and the function in your bean class:

```
public boolean filterByDate(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {

    String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
    if (filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM);

    Date filterDate = (Date) value;
    Date dateFrom;
    Date dateTo;
    try {
        String fromPart = filterText.substring(0, filterText.indexOf("-"));
        String toPart = filterText.substring(filterText.indexOf("-") + 1);
        dateFrom = fromPart.isEmpty() ? null : df.parse(fromPart);
        dateTo = toPart.isEmpty() ? null : df.parse(toPart);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "unable to parse date: " + filterText, pe);
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log("another exception");
        return false;
    }

    return (dateFrom == null || filterDate.after(dateFrom)) && (dateTo == null || filterDate.before(dateTo));
}
```

}

you can also read this answer: [Primefaces datatable date range filter with filterFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791039/primefaces-datatable-date-range-filter-with-filterfunction)

Comment: i implemented the solution with sessionscoped but i get this error msg:12:50:37,624 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-23) Error Rendering View[/pages/listDemandes.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /pages/listDemandes.xhtml @43,138 filterFunction="#{demandeBean.filterByDate}": java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: the debug show me an error at this line:                                                                           DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM);